# DFA of Binary numbers decimal equivalent divisible by some.number n

Tags: automata

Hello we may construct DFA for binary equivalent decimal divisible by 3 for eg if we read a string 001 then first we read 0 and for next 0 we will shift towards left so it's 00 next if we read 1 00 will be left shifted and place 1 in 2^0 position so it is 1*(2^0) + 0*(2^1) +0*(2^2).....we read this string as 001 but what i want is I want a DFA for which reading a binary string is divisible by some n for eg if we want 3 for 3 like that......show be binary string divisible by 3 buy reading 001 have no left shift but places every bit in increasing powers......I.e reading 001 should be read as 0 in first position  and second 0in second position &1 in third position....I.e 001 is read as 0*(2^0) + 0*(2^1) + 1*(2^1)..so it is 100 if we read from left .....but if we read it from right it is 001 I want DFA for this machine reading string from right to left

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - You need to be more clear in expression your needs. Please organize your thoughts into paragraphs and ask a single, clear question.

Comment: See the answer on your other question. The steps I go through are very easy to adapt to strings written the other way around. Indeed, that's the way I originally solved it, but I decided to render it in Big-Endian before submitting.